# How to get only class value of a class with multiple values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code and I need to get the obj.tileClass only but instead I get "XXXXX tile"

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in draggableObjects" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($index, $data,$event)">

     <div class="{{obj.tileClass}} tile">
           <a href="{{obj.tileLink}}" ng-click="stopClick($data, $event)">
             <div class="tileBody">
                 <h4>{{obj.tileHeader}}</h4>
                 <p>{{obj.tileContent}}</p>
             </div>

             <div class="tileFooter">
                 <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </div>
           </a>
     </div>

</li>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.onDropComplete = function (index, obj, evt) {
    var otherObj = $scope.draggableObjects[index];
    var otherIndex = $scope.draggableObjects.indexOf(obj);
    $scope.draggableObjects[index] = obj;
    $scope.draggableObjects[otherIndex] = otherObj;

    angular.forEach($scope.draggableObjects, function(value, key){
        console.log("tile " + value.tileClass);
    });
```

I need to get only XXXX. Cna anyone help me?

my data:

```
tiles: [
    {tileClass: "fileTile"}, 
    {tileClass: "videoTile"}, 
    {tileClass: "linkTile"},
    {tileClass: "fileTile"}
];
```

This data is appended to `li` elements which has already a `class="tile"` so the result will be i.e.

```
<li class="tile fileTile">*****</li>
```

When the tiles are rearranged, I need to get the class and store to DB, but instead of getting only i.e. `"fileTile"` I get the entire class value `"tile fileTile"`.

Comment: So here I get   "tile fileTile" but I need only the "fileTile"

Comment: please provide your data

Comment: @DiegoPolidoSantana my data: tiles: [{tileClass: "fileTile"}, {tileClass: "videoTile"}, {tileClass: "linkTile"}, {tileClass: "fileTile"}].   This data is appended to li elements which has already a class="tile" so the result will be i.e. <li class="tile fileTile">*****</li>. When the tiles are rearranged, I need to get the class and store to DB, but instead of getting only i.e. "fileTile"  I get the entire class value  "tile fileTile"

Comment: How do you get that className? (onClick, onDrag etc...)

Comment: @ngDeveloper I added the code showing how I get the class value

Comment: Why can't you simply read each `obj.tileClass` instead of trying to extract it from the className?   It's always going to be easier to use the data model you already have the to try to parse stuff out of the DOM...  (On closer inspection, it looks like that's what you're already doing... and the extra "tile " is appearing because you're putting that in as part of the console.log?)